# 200 stream not found with cakePHP dialog box

Tags: jquery, cakephp, dialog, flowplayer

I am getting an error when trying to play a file in cakephp using a jQuery dialog box. The player starts perfectly but I am unable to get it to play any of the files, I get a 200 stram not found stream.play.streamnotfound error.

I have tried a great number of variations but cannot get the path correct, or atleast correct that it plays or downloads the audio file, if I paste the path correctly it works.

My files are located at /trunk/app/webroot/files/uploads/type/filename.wav

Here is the code I am using:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
       flowplayer("player", "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>/app/webroot/js/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.11.swf"); 
});
</script>
 <?php
 echo $this->Html->link("","/trunk/files/uploads/questions/4fe044ad-aec4-408f-9c20-13acfe6ba31b.wav",array("id" => "player")); 
 ?>
```

Even if i put the correct link in above, it still does not play (by direct link I mean including the localhost ect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moved to video.js, could not resolve the issue